# Determining the Authentication Method Used by bcp and jdbc in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I have been working on using the bcp utility to transfer data to and from SQL Server. I am currently interested in understanding how to determine the authentication method being used by bcp when connecting to SQL Server.

Specifically, I would like to distinguish whether bcp is using a service account or an interactive user account for authentication. I have read about the -T option for trusted connections (Windows Authentication), but I want to confirm if bcp is indeed using this mechanism.

Reason for this is I was able to connect with SQL Server on remote machine using this jdbc string

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server:1433;db;Domain=domain;useNTLMv2=true;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

but am not able to do the same using

```
bcp.exe [db].[dbo].[table] in "file.txt" -S server,1433 -t "|**|" -e ..\logs\error.txt -w -T -k
```

I am getting

> SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\user'

If both will be using the same authentication means why I am getting this error only on bcp

I am getting this SQL exception while trying to connect SQL Server and I am not able to find the reason.

Comment: What's the real question? The *user* specifies the authentication method which means you already know what that is - you explicitly specified it in the command line and the connection string. In both cases you've specified Windows authentication which means the connection is done using the current Window's user's account

Comment: `using a service account or an interactive user account` that's a completely different question that only has meaning when using Windows authentication. The *server* doesn't know or care what the account is as long as it's a valid server login with the correct permissions. If you get a `Login failed for user` it means a different account was used, one that has no permission to connect to the server. If the same domain user runs both `bcp` and the Java application, both should succeed

Comment: Check the server logins in the remote server using eg SSMS or Azure Data Studio. I suspect you won't find `domain\user` among them.

Comment: Aside... people are still using jTDS? It hasn't seen a release in over ten years already (June 2013), move on to something modern and supported.